# Pivot column to row or create view table column name as value

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot-table

I have create a table tvc

```
CREATE TABLE  tvc(tvcid number(10), tvcname  varchar2(15));
```

and another table  uvc

```
CREATE  TABLE uvc( uname  varchar(10) );
```

How can insert data to  uvc table  or create view  uvc from tvc table column name?

- tvcid
- tvcname

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply create view for this instead of creating a separate table:

```
CREATE view uvc
AS
SELECT tvcid as ID,
       tvcname as Name
FROM   tvc
```

Answer (score 0):

1. How can I insert data into `uvc` table?

   ```
   INSERT INTO uvc (uname)
   SELECT tvc.tvcname 
   FROM tvc 
   [WHERE ..some conditions..]
   ```

   Note that `tvc.tvcname` and `uvc.uname` types mismatch, so you should change 
   `uvc.uname` datatype to `varchar2(15)` to avoid errors.
2. How can I create view `uvc` from `tvc`?

   ```
   CREATE VIEW uvc AS
   SELECT tvc.tvcname uname
   FROM tvc
   [WHERE ..some conditions..];
   ```

Comment: @khan You certainly can, but in case you have `tvcname` longer than 10 symbols you'll get an error

Comment: which  Where condition i have use?

Comment: `WHERE` clause is optional, you may not use it at all if you don't need to.

Comment: actually i want to insert  column name not column data such  tvcid
tvcname  to uvc.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this:

```
with tb1 AS(
     select 1 tvcid, 'gg' tvcname from dual
     union all
     select 2 tvcid, 'gg2' tvcname from dual
), tb2 as (
 select  'gg' uname from dual
 union all
 select  'gg' uname from dual
)
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM
TB1 LEFT JOIN TB2 ON 1 = 1
```